# Wordpress get_permalink($this->get_pageid()) showing wrong url

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using `get_permalink($this->get_pageid())` for getting page url.

my permalink is enables as sample-post. It should be `example.com/forum` but it is showing `example.com/login`

Comment: Show your full code for better help

Comment: `$this->get_pageid()` does not sound like a valid method. Please show some code if you'd like a proper answer.

Comment: @Karl Yes you are right it was a method in my class. i resolved it. there was some error in method query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear because `get_pageid()` is not a wordpress' native function and you didn't provide any code. Anyways...

Actually [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) expects an optional `id` as an argument which should be an integer and this is required only when you are using it outside the loop so make sure your `$this->get_pageid()` returns an integer value. For an example it should be something like this

```
get_permalink(10) // 10 should be your page/post id
```

Also you can use

```
get_permalink(get_page_by_title('Some Page')) // Some Page is page/post title
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
global $post;
get_permalink($post->ID); // $post->ID will return the page/post id
```

when you are outside of the loop. Hope this helps.